# Retrieving appsettings with IOptions<T> in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET Core 3.0, I'm unable to retrieve the values of my `appsettings.json`.

appsettings.[environment.]json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "MySettings": {
    "Option1": "value1",
    "Option2": "value2",
[...]
    }
}
```

model.cs:

```
    public class AllSettings
    {
        public MySettings MySettings { get; }

        public static AllSettings Instance = new AllSettings();

        public AllSettings()
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    }

    public class MySettings
    {
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
[...]
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            Configuration = builder;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
[...]
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<AllSettings>(Configuration);
        }
```

And here in my function where the usage is failing with a null value.

```
        public string Testing()
        {
            var settings = AllSettings.Instance;
            var option1 = settings.MySettings.Option1; //null
            return option1;
        }
```

What am I missing, here?

Example I based this off of:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/asp-net-core-3-0-configuration-factsheet/

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking if your `appsettings.{env}.json` files are configured for being copied to output directory. It should be either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image]

Your `ConfigurationBuilder` is looking for your configuration files in `env.ContentRootPath` (as per your code) so the files should be accessible from that place.

Comment: for me this solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is `appsettings.[environment.]json` a real file name in your project?
It should be `appsettings.Development.json` or `appsettings.Release.json`.

Next, there is no `set` on `MySettings` property.

Another side thing - do not use static instances. It defeats the whole DI purpose. Instead, inject `IOptions<AllSettings>` wherever needed.

Startup.cs

```
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
[...]
            services.Configure<AllSettings>(Configuration);
        }
```

TestController.cs

```
[...]
  TestController(IOptions<AllSettings> settings){
    _settings = settings.Value;
  }

  [HttpGet(nameof(TestAction))]
  public MySettings TestAction() {
    return _settings.MySettings;
  }
[...]
```

Comment: No, the file is `appsettings.Development,json`, etc as you noted. Added a setter, no change. You're going to need to expand on what you mean by the last bit. Can you provide a functional example?

Comment: Thanks, though how is this supposed to work if you have a functionA in ClassA calling a functionB in ClassB where functionB has the `IOptions` parameter? Seems like a lot of extra work to pass that parameter in from function to function.

Comment: You inject it in every class which needs it, not pass in parameters. There is additional work but it's not "a lot". And the benefits of DI are well known - there's plenty resources online - I wouldn't reiterate them here.

Comment: Please note, this is not the main issue. I think you should start with a fresh asp.net core 3.0 project. The code you had in Startup constructor is old - settings are now configured in a default builder in Program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

> Startup.cs

```
public static ConfigurationSetting RegisterConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<ConfigurationSetting>(configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var iop = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ConfigurationSetting>>();
            return iop.Value;
        }
```

> In any other class inject like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private ConfigurationSetting configSetting;
  public HomeController(IOptions<ConfigurationSetting> op)
  {
    configSetting = op.Value;
  }
}
```